# Python ZipFile: remove embedded archive from a containing file

Tags: python, zip

There a technic of store ZIP archive concatenated with some other file (e. g. with EXE to store additional resources or with JPEG for steganography). Python's `ZipFile` supports such files (e. g. if you open `ZipFile` in "a" mode on non-ZIP file, it will append ZIP headers to the end). I would like to update such archive (possible add, update and delete files from ZIP archive).

Python's `ZipFile` doesn't support deleting and overriding of the files inside the archive, only appending, so the only way for me is completely recreate ZIP file with new contents. But I need to conserve the main file in which ZIP was embedded. If I just open it in "w" mode, the whole file has completed overridden.

I need a way how to remove a ZIP file from the end of an ordinary file. I'd prefer use only functions which are available in Python 3 standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
min_header_offset = None
with ZipFile(output_filename, "r") as zip_file:
    for info in zip_file.infolist():
        if min_header_offset is None or info.header_offset < min_header_offset:
            min_header_offset = info.header_offset
        # Here also possible to save existing files if them needed for update
if min_header_offset is not None:
    with open(output_filename, "r+b") as f:
        f.truncate(min_header_offset)
# Somehow populate new archive contents
with ZipFile(args.output, "a") as zip_file:
    for input_filename in input_filenames:
        zip_file.write(input_filename)
```

It clears the archive, but don't touch anything what is going before the archive.